# How to display contents of first page using localStorage in second page

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, dom, local-storage

I am new to phonegap. I trying to display contents of first page only when a valid user logins in second page. I am using below script to achieve this. But i am not getting how to display first page contents after changepage is called using localStorage?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Submit a form via AJAX</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <script>
        function onSuccess(data, status)
        {
            data = $.trim(data);
            //$("#notification").text(data);
            alert(data);

            if(data=="SUCCESS"){

                // store some data
                storeObject.username = $("#username").val();
                storeObject.email = $("#email").val();

                //change page
                $.mobile.changePage("#secondPage");
            }
        }

        function onError(data, status)
        {
            // handle an error
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
                      $("#submit").click(function(){

                                         var formData = $("#callAjaxForm").serialize();

                                         $.ajax({
                                                type: "POST",
                                                url: “myURL”,
                                                cache: false,
                                                data: formData,
                                                success: onSuccess,
                                                error: onError
                                                });

                                         return false;
                                         });
        });


        // Store object
        var storeObject = {
            username : '',
            email    : ''
        }

        //not getting below alert when second page loads 
        $(document).on('pageaftershow', '#secondPage', function(){ 
           alert("Second page"); <--- **NOT DISPLAYING WHEN SECONDPAGE LOADS**   
           alert('My name is ' + storeObject.username + ' ' +  storeObject.email);
         });

       </script>

    <!-- call first page -->
    <div data-role="page" id="firstPage">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Call Ajax</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <form id="callAjaxForm">
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="username">User Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value=""  />

                    <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" value=""  />

                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value=""  />

                    <label for="lastName">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value=""  />

                    <button data-theme="b" id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer">
            <h1>footer</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- call secondPage page -->
    <div data-role="page" id="secondPage">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Second page</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer">
            <h1>footer</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set and get localstorage data like this way

**Set Your content**

```
       if(data=="SUCCESS"){

            // store some data
            localStorage.setItem('username',$("#username").val());
            localStorage.setItem('email',$("#email").val());

            //change page
            $.mobile.changePage("#secondPage");
        }
```

**Get Content in second page**

```
localStorage.getItem('username');
localStorage.getItem('email');
```

Comment: Not even getting alert message "Second page"

Comment: Please inspect your page and see is there any error?